# vagrantfile cookbook path

Tags: vagrant

I want to set the cookbook path to a certain place, so that I don't need to 
modify the Vagrantfile everytime(after vagrant init).

I find [Vagrantfile](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/vagrantfile.html) load several places, so I decide to set my cookbook path info 
in ~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile,(this file is the 3rd of Vagrantfile Load Order) like:

```
...
   config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
     chef.cookbooks_path = ["D:/lib/chef/cookbooks"]
     chef.add_recipe "dev::default"
   end
...
```

but when I make a new vm, and modify Vagrantfile(this file is the 4th of Vagrantfile Load Order):

```
...
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
     chef.add_recipe "torch"
  end
...
```

error:

```
[2013-02-28T03:23:36+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-02-28T03:23:36+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-02-28T03:23:36+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-02-28T03:23:36+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook torch not found. If
you're loading torch from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

but I am sure the specific cookbook is under my cookbook path.

Comment: I recommend using [librarian-chef](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian-chef) for managing your cookbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps: 
- Create a folder cookbooks in the vagrantfile's directory
- checkout the cookbooks to this directory
- add the following to your vagrantfile

```
 chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks"]
```

hope to have helped

Comment: Maybe I did not explain my problem clearly. I add the cookbooks_path to the 3rd load place(http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/vagrantfile.html )( Vagrantfile Load Order part). And don't want to add it again at 4th load place...